# Gradle - how to set up-to-date parameters on a predefined task?

Tags: gradle

I could really use some help with this!

The gradle docs say that to make the up-to-date logic to function, just do this:

```
task transform {
    ext.srcFile = file('mountains.xml')
    ext.destDir = new File(buildDir, 'generated')
    inputs.file srcFile
    outputs.dir destDir
```

This is all well and good for tasks you are defining.  However, I am using the eclipse plugin to do some modification to the .classpath file.  Up-to-date does not work. That is, it runs the task over and over again out of the box (at least for me).  Here is what I have:

```
eclipse {
    classpath {
        //eclipseClasspath.inputs.file // something like this??? but what to set it to?
        //eclipseClasspath.outputs.file //  here too
        file {
            withXml {

                def node = it.asNode()
                // rest of my stuff here
```

I tried a couple of things where I have the two commented out lines.  Since those didn't work, I realized I didn't really have a clue and could use some help!  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, the Eclipse tasks should not rerun every single time.  That makes me think that you are doing something to cause either the inputs or outputs to change.  If you are modifying your Eclipse project after Gradle generates it or changing dependencies, etc, you would naturally be triggering the upToDate checks.

If you really do need to force it to run every time, you might be able to get it to work with this.  I'm not sure if I've ever tried using this when other outputs are already defined.

```
eclipseClasspath {
  outputs.upToDateWhen { true } //there isn't an equivalent for inputs
}
```

One important note is that what you were using is the Eclipse model that describes your project, not the actual task itself:

```
eclipse {  //this is the eclipse model
  classpath {

  }
}

eclipseClasspath {
  //this is a task
}

eclipseProject {
  //this is a task
}
```

Comment: When I said it runs it over and over again above, that may have been misleading.  What I meant was that if I run the "eclipseClasspath" task directly repeatedly from the command line, via: gradle eclipseClasspath, I do not ever get an "Up-To-Date".  Instead, it re-runs the task.  All I am trying to do is to ensure that 'src/main/generated' is added as a classpathentry, but I want it automatic, not something users need to do and/or know about.